# test for available data in filehandle

Tags: perl, sockets, file-descriptor

For some reason I am implementing some specific network protocol similar to STOMP in plain pure Perl.

The connection can be either a direct network socket, or an SSL tunnel provided by `openssl s_client` created by a call to `open3` (no `IO::Socket::SSL` available on the host).

Depending on the dialog a request to the server may or may not have a response, or may have multiple responses. How can I test the file descriptors for the existence of data? Currently when no data is available, it waits until the defined timeout.

**EDIT**: I have probably a vocabulary issue between file handle vs. file descriptor to perform my research. I just found that `eof()` may help but cannot use it correctly yet.

While it is a bit complicated to provide an SCCCE, here is the interesting parts of the code:

```perl
# creation of a direct socket connection 
sub connect_direct_socket {
    my ($host, $port) = @_;
    my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET(PeerAddr => $host,
                                    PeerPort => $port,
                                    Proto    => 'tcp') or die "Can't connect to $host:$port\n";
    $sock->autoflush(1);
    say STDERR "* connected to $host port $port" if $args{verbose} || $args{debug};
    
    return $sock, $sock, undef;
}

# for HTTPS, we are "cheating" by creating a tunnel with OpenSSL in s_client mode
my $tunnel_pid;
sub connect_ssl_tunnel {
    my ($dest) = @_;
    my ($host, $port);
    $host = $dest->{host};
    $port = $dest->{port};
    
    my $cmd = "openssl s_client -connect ${host}:${port} -servername ${host} -quiet";# -quiet -verify_quiet -partial_chain';
    $tunnel_pid = open3(*CMD_IN, *CMD_OUT, *CMD_ERR, $cmd);
    say STDERR "* connected via OpenSSL to $host:$port" if $args{verbose} || $args{debug};
    say STDERR "* command = $cmd" if $args{debug};

    $SIG{CHLD} = sub {
        print STDERR "* REAPER: status $? on ${tunnel_pid}\n" if waitpid($tunnel_pid, 0) > 0 && $args{debug};
    };
    return *CMD_IN, *CMD_OUT, *CMD_ERR;
}

# later
($OUT, $IN, $ERR) = connect_direct_socket($url->{host}, $url->{port});
# or
($OUT, $IN, $ERR) = connect_ssl_tunnel($url);

# then I am sending with a
print $OUT $request;
# and read the response with
my $selector = IO::Select->new();
$selector->add($IN);

FRAME:
while (my @ready = $selector->can_read($args{'max-wait'} || $def_max_wait)) {
    last unless @ready;
    foreach my $fh (@ready) {
        if (fileno($fh) == fileno($IN)) {
            my $buf_size = 1024 * 1024;
            my $block = $fh->sysread(my $buf, $buf_size);
            if($block){
                if ($buf =~ s/^\n*([^\n].*?)\n\n//s){
                    # process data here
                }
                if ($buf =~ s/^(.*?)\000\n*//s ){
                    goto EOR;
                    # next FRAME;
                }                }
            $selector->remove($fh) if eof($fh);
        }
    }
}
EOR:
```

**EDIT 2 and epilogue**

As a summary, depending in the protocol dialog

- a request can have an expected response (for instance a `CONNECT` must return a `CONNECTED`)
- a request to get the pending messages can return a single response, multiple responses at once (without intermediate request), or no response (and in this case the `can_read()` with no parameter of Ikegami is blocking, what I want to avoid).

Thanks to Ikegami I have changed my code as the following:

- the timeout argument to `can_read()` is passed as an argument to the sub that is processing the responses
- for initial connections I am passing a timeout of several seconds
- when I expect instant responses I am passing a timeout of 1 second
- in the process loop, after any correct response I replace the initial timeout by a `0.1` to not block if no more data is waiting in the filehandle

Here is my updated code:

```perl
sub process_stomp_response {
    my $IN = shift;
    my $timeout = shift;

    my $resp = [];
    my $buf;                    # allocate the buffer once and not in loop - thanks Ikegami!
    my $buf_size = 1024 * 1024;

    my $selector = IO::Select->new();
    $selector->add($IN);

  FRAME:
    while (1){
        my @ready = $selector->can_read($timeout);
        last FRAME unless @ready;     # empty array = timed-out
        foreach my $fh (@ready) {
            if (fileno($fh) == fileno($IN)) {
                my $bytes = $fh->sysread($buf, $buf_size);
                # if bytes undef -> error, if 0 -> eof, else number of read bytes
                my %frame;
                if (defined $bytes){
                    if($bytes){
                        if ($buf =~ s/^\n*([^\n].*?)\n\n//s){
                            # process frame headers here
                            # [...]
                        }
                        if ($buf =~ s/^(.*?)\000\n*//s ){
                            # process frame body here
                            # [...]
                            push @$resp, \%frame;
                            $timeout = 0.1; # for next read short timeout
                            next FRAME;
                        }
                    } else {
                        # EOF
                        $selector->remove($fh); 
                        last FRAME;
                    }
                } else {
                    # something is wrong
                    say STDERR "Error reading STOMP response: $!";
                }
            } else {
                # what? not the given fh
            }
        }
    }
    return $resp;
}
```

Comment: Re "*`my $buf`*", This is a bug. You should be reusing the same buffer for the entire communication because `sysread` can easily return only part of a block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* use `eof` in conjunction with `select` (which `can_read` wraps). It performs a buffered read, which breaks `select`.

`select` will mark a handle as ready for reading when it reaches EOF, and `sysread` returns zero on EOF. So all you need to do to detect EOF is to check for `sysread` returning zero.

Note that using a new buffer for every pass was a mistake `sysread` can easily return only part of a message. The following fixes this, and shows how to handle errors and EOF from `sysread`.

Globals:

```perl
my %clients_by_fd;
```

When you get a new connection:

```perl
$selector->add( $fh );
$clients_by_fd{ fileno( $fh ) } = {
   buf => "",
   # Any other info you want here.
};
```

Event loop:

```perl
while ( 1 ) {
   my @ready = $selector->can_read();
   for my $fh ( @ready ) {
      my $client = $clients_by_fd{ fileno( $fh ) };

      my $buf_ref = \$client->{ buf };

      my $rv = sysread( $fh, $$buf_ref, 1024*1024, length( $$buf_ref ) );
      if ( !$rv ) {
         if ( defined( $rv ) ) {
            # EOF
            if ( length( $$buf_ref ) ) {
               warn( "Error reading: Incomplete message\n" );
            }
         } else {
            # Error
            warn( "Error reading: $!\n" );
         }

         delete $clients_by_fd{ fileno( $fh ) };
         $select->remove( $fh );
      }

      while ( $$buf_ref =~ s/^.*?\n\n//s ) {
         process_message( $client, $& );
      }
   }
}
```